# Mongoose fails to updateMany with $switch operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I tried to use [an example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) in the official document of mongodb,

```
db.students3.updateMany({ },
[
 { $set: { grade: { $switch: {
                       branches: [
                           { case: { $gte: [ "$average", 90 ] }, then: "A" },
                           { case: { $gte: [ "$average", 80 ] }, then: "B" },
                           { case: { $gte: [ "$average", 70 ] }, then: "C" },
                           { case: { $gte: [ "$average", 60 ] }, then: "D" }
                       ],
                       default: "F"
 } } } }
])
```

Property `grade` is defined as `Number` type. I got the error, when tried to update all documents in the database students3,

```
CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "{ '$switch': { branches: [ [Object] ] } }" (type Object) at path "grade"
```

Could someone explain the error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `$trunc` first, then `average` field would be created.

```
{ $set: { average : { $trunc: [ { $avg: "$tests" }, 0 ] }, modified: "$$NOW" } }
```

complete update

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      average: { $trunc: [ { $avg: "$tests" }, 0 ] },
      modified: "$$NOW"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      grade: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            { case: { $gte: [ "$average", 90 ] }, then: "A" },
            { case: { $gte: [ "$average", 80 ] }, then: "B" },
            { case: { $gte: [ "$average", 70 ] }, then: "C" },
            { case: { $gte: [ "$average", 60 ] }, then: "D" }
          ],
          default: "F"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_S2HfDH5Q_c)